# Gson: How pass JsonObject/JsonElement as serializable?

Tags: java, kotlin, gson

In my Kotlin project I must use `com.google.gson.JsonObject`.

```
val jsonRedir = JsonObject()
someCustomMethod(jsonRedir)
```

The problem is that method `someCustomMethod` has one Serializable paramter. But `JsonObject` is not `Serializable`.

How I can fix this?

I must pass exact `JsonElement` or `JsonObject` to `someCustomMethod`

Comment: either change the method header or wrap the JsonObject, you can't change JsonObject to be Serializable if it isn't

Comment: You can create a new class that extends `JsonObject` and implements `Serializable` and pass object of this class to `someCustomMethod`

Comment: @AshishkumarSingh JsonObject  class is final

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class that can serialize/deserialize your JsonObject by implementing `Serializable` interface and implementing `writeObject` and `readObject` like below:

```
class JsonObjectSerializer(val gson: Gson, val jsonObject: JsonObject) : Serializable {

    @Throws(ClassNotFoundException::class, IOException::class)
    private fun readObject(aInputStream: ObjectInputStream) {
        val gson = aInputStream.readUTF()
        jsonObject = this.gson.fromJson(gson, JsonObject::class.java!!)
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun writeObject(aOutputStream: ObjectOutputStream) {
        aOutputStream.writeUTF(gson.toJson(jsonObject))
    }
}
```